# Is there a way to add text to the end of a string in a conf file in linux?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, terminal, echo, ubuntu-16.04

I have a problem: I have a file that, if I knew how, I would like to edit from the command. I would like to locate the file by content on that line.

I am in CyberPatriot, and my team is second in my state. I know someone who is on the number one team and I know one of the people on the first team. It kills me so I want to make a list of commands that I can go off of to make it faster and more efficient.

Imagine I had this file:

```
example
oof
goo
random
yes
```

and I wanted to change it to this:

```
example
oof
goo
random 'added text'
yes
```

How do I do so?
I know I can use the `echo` command to add text to the end of a file, but I don't know how to add text to the end of a specific line.

Thanks, Owen

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271475/insert-text-at-specific-line-number/277015
Check this might help

Comment: Thank you very much, however, this question is asking how to make a new line rather than adding to an existing one.

Comment: If you have command line access, use 'vi', 'emacs' or 'ed' to modify the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use sed for this purpose.

```
sed 's/random/& Hello World/' file
```

to append text to the matched string.

You can use `^random$` to make sure the entire line is matched, before appending.

If you need to modify the file directly, you can use the `-i` flag, which facilitates in-place editing. Further, using `-i.bak` creates a backup of the original file first before modifying it, as in

```
sed -i.bak 's/random/& Hello World/' file
```

The original copy of the file can be found in `file.bak`

More about `sed` : https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html

Comment: You are quick! Good answer. Referral to the manual is great (but most are hear because they don't read it....) so any thing else you can add that completes the picture makes it a more helpful answer.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Agreed. Have added more info. Thank you for the suggestions :)

Comment: Thank you. If I could vote twice I would. I have always found answering questions that you step into the role of teacher. The quality answers are the ones that carry the topic (even if briefly) throughout what the questioner appears to intend to do. (at least that is how I try and approach it). We all remember teachers that left us more confused than when we walked in... Being a good teacher is key.

Comment: Thanks, this was my first time asking on Stack Overflow, and I was suprised with how fast and good my answers were.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like below

```
sed '4!d' file | xargs -I{} sed -i "4s/{}/{} \'added text\'/" file
```

Basically in the above command, we are getting the 4th line of the file using sed `sed '4!d' file` and then using this line to replace it with the same text and some new text(`added text`)

Comment: Thank you, however, I would like to locate the file by content, instead of line number.